# Split observable on error in RxJS

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, rxjs5

With promises, we can use a variant of `.then` to split up the chain when an error occurs. Here is an example using `fetch`

```
fetch('http://website.com').then(
  // Perform some logic
  (response) => response.json().then(({ answer }) => `Your answer: ${answer}`),
  // Skip json parsing when an error occurs
  (error) => 'An error occurred :(',
).then(console.log);
```

This allows me to skip the response processing logic and only respond to errors that were raised in the original fetch statement. Something similar in RxJS might look like this:

```
Observable.fromPromise(fetch('http://website.com'))
  // if I put .catch here, the result will be piped into flatMap and map
  .flatMap(response => response.json())
  .map(({ answer }) => `Your answer: ${answer}`)
  // if I put .catch here, errors thrown in flatMap and map will also be caught
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

As the comments in the code state, I can't simply put a catch operator in as it doesn't have the same behaviour as my promise chain.

I know I can get it with custom operators involving materialising, or merging an error catching observable with this one, but it all seems like pretty major overkill. Is there a simple way to achieve the promise chain behaviour?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, if I was in your situation I wouldn't be worried about catching errors from `flatMap` and `map`. When the source Observable throws an error then it'll be propagated to the observer. So I'd just use an error handler when calling subscribe (otherwise the error is rethrown):

```
.subscribe(console.log, err => console.log('error:', err));
```

Note that when an error occurs in the source Observable (a Promise in your case) that it's propagated as `error` notifications, not as standard `next` notifications. **This means that `flatMap()` and `map()` won't have absolutely any effect on the error message**. If you used `catch()` or `materialize()` that both operators (`flatMap` and `map`) would have to be able to handle this type of data (and not throw yet another error).

Anyway you can always use `share()` or `publish()`  and make two different subscriptions where each handles only one type of signals:

```
let source = Observable.fromPromise(fetch('http://website.com')).publish();

source
  .subscribe(undefined, err => console.log(err));

source
  .flatMap(...)
  .map(...)
  .subscribe(console.log, () => {});

source.connect();
```

Now I have a separate observer only for errors.

Note that I had to make an empty callback with `() => {}` so the error will be silently ignored. Also note that when using multicasting (the `publish()` operator) then the Subject inside might have some specific behavior I should be aware of but maybe it doesn't matter in your use-case.

Comment: The reason I want to differentiate between the two kinds of errors is because I can reasonably recover, or give some kind of feedback from an error from `fetch` (e.g. something is wrong with your network). 

If an error occurs in flatMap or map, it's likely my own error, so I'd want the error to propagate to the subscriber.

Comment: I like your solution, but I my goal is to have the result (in this case a string from an error or parsing the json) be part of the same observable. Would you recommend just merging the two?

Comment: Than I'd probably use `catch()` right after `Observable.fromPromise()` and just wrapped the error with my own error class (`catch()` can also rethrow the error with your own error class as `error` signal). Later in the observer I can check whether the error is typeof or implements certain class. This means I can check whether the error happened in `fromPromise` and was caught with `catch()` or from eg. `map` and is a regular error. Maybe have a look at the `retryWhen()` operator that catches errors as well but let's you automatically resubscribe based on your own notifications...